# How To Use Jquery Closest To Apply Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I am trying to color the `border` of `ul` using jquery `closest` from `div` whose `class` is `.row` and color the `border` of `ul` is `red`. But it seems like the jquery is not working and does not show any color in `ul` `border`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row").closest("ul").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Name To Be Displayed
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Help using jquery closest to do so will be a great Help.

Comment: You have to read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) first. Pay particular attention to the description and the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below snippet. You are using the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
     {
       $(".row").find("ul").css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Name To Be Displayed
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`closest` wont work in this case since it search element in upward direction that is the first ancestor of the selected element. Instead you can use `find` method

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".row").find("ul").css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fLeh2yav/1/)